# Send intent to only one object recipient in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to send `Intent` in Android to only one definite object, if there exist more objects of similar class in this and other applications?

Generating unique action id for each object of the same class and then using action id to address the object looks like one solution, but is there a better way?

Some background on the situation.

There is Activity Recognition engine in Android. If a client wants to receive activity updates, client passes `PendingIntent` to Activity Recognition engine. At every moment when user's activity is recognized, new information is put to Intent from `PendingIntent` and fired back.

Now, I am writing a handy helper class that will wrap all this `PendingIntent`/`Intent` machinery and will provide received `ActivtiyRecognitionResult` in some simple manner for further processing. And if there is more that one application using the same handy helper class, or more than one instance of handy helper class in one application, there will be a mess with those identically-looking `PendingIntents`/`Intents` and identically-looking (from intent point of view) handy helper objects.

Comment: The activity recognition event handler is a BroadcastReciver?

Comment: Yes, I can make it a BroadcastReceiver without any problem